# Syntax error on function declaration in Python

Tags: python, function, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to write a simple network server in Python, unfortunately I'm falling at the simple hurdle of getting a function to work!

```
import os, socket

class serv:
    def __init__(self):
        self.host
        self.port = 'localhost', 58008
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((self.host, self.port)

    def send(self, msg):
        self.conn.send(msg + end)

    def run(self):
        self.socket.listen(1)
        self.conn
        self.addr = self.socket.accept()
        send(self, msg="Hello, world")

S = serv()
S.run()
```

This code gives the following error on the function call send:

```
File "server.py", line 10
def send(self, msg):
  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

If it helps (I'm sure it won't), I'm doing this on a Raspberry Pi using Adafruit WebIDE.

Comment: When in doubt: check the line preceding the error. Odds are you are missing a parenthesis or bracket.

Answer (score 11):

You've forgotten a closing parenthesis in the line before.

But there are also other errors that you'll encounter once the parsing stage is survived. For example, you're referencing undefined names (that'll give you `NameError`s): `self.host` or `self.conn`.

Comment: That's got it! Thanks for pointing out the other bits too, I've just fixed those.

Answer (score 0):

all about closing bracket. It is not enough in the next line:

```
self.socket.bind((self.host, self.port)
```